# How "modern" is K.A.J?

Tags: communities, yekke

"Traditionally", K.A.J (Khal Adat Yeshurun, the Yekkishe Kehilla in Washington Heights) was the "successor" Kehilla of R' Hirsh, following the Torah Im Derekh Eretz model.

Do they still follow that model? Do their Rabbonim insist that  their followers receive a strong secular education, do they still insist on/or at least condone attending university? Do their Rabbonim still attend University (many Rabbonim did in pre-war Germany)?

Comment: Apparently not so much: http://www.vosizneias.com/17487/2008/06/26/new-york-city-reb-shimshon-raphael-hirsch-torah-im-derech-eretz-philosophy-at-height-of-controversy/

Comment: 2 questions from you about Breuers perks me to ask if you have ever lived in Wash. Heights and if so, when?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Good. Other than the immediate few blocks surrounding YU and Breuer's you wouldn't want to be there without a firearm.

Answer (score 2):

Most would tell you that it's not really "modern" at this point in that sense.

[The current official line](http://www.vosizneias.com/17487/2008/06/26/new-york-city-reb-shimshon-raphael-hirsch-torah-im-derech-eretz-philosophy-at-height-of-controversy/) is that Rabbi Hirsch was great enough to decide what amount of cultural integration was right in his time; but today in his absence, we follow "today's Gedolim" on the matter, who are more reluctant.

Effectively it's more like an Agudah synagogue, with certain different rituals. There are plenty of college-educated professionals there, but when one individual publicly lamented that the next generation is being geared towards Lakewood and this was not what Hirsch intended, he was harshly criticized.